# flowplayer multiple player on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add on the same page 2 players with chapters navigation, I use this page [demo](http://demos.flowplayer.org/scripting/chapters.html) to create my page with 2 players. All works the only problem is player1 depend on player:

```
<div id="player" ></div>
<div id="player1" ></div>
```

If I remove the first player

```
<div id="player" ></div>
```

on page player1 is invisible. I had script below on my page (script of player in first)

```
<script>
$(function () {
var elems = $(“#chapters a”),
chaptertoggle = function (index) {
elems.each(function (i) {
$(this).toggleClass(“active”, index == i);
});
},
clearchapters = function () {
elems.removeClass(“active”);
},
api = flowplayer(“#player”, {
 ratio: 5/12,
rtmp: "rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
cuepoints: [5.5, 12, 17.5, 23.7, 27, 30.5],
clip: {
  sources: [
    { type: "video/webm",   src: "//stream.flowplayer.org/playful.webm" },
    { type: "video/mp4",    src: "//stream.flowplayer.org/playful.mp4" },
    { type: "video/flash",  src: "mp4:playful" }
  ]
},
splash: true,
embed: {
  skin: "//releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.4/skin/playful.css"
}
.................</script>

<script>
$(function () {
var elems = $(“#chapters2 a”),
chaptertoggle = function (index) {
elems.each(function (i) {
$(this).toggleClass(“active”, index == i);
});
},
clearchapters = function () {
elems.removeClass(“active”);
},
api = flowplayer(“#player1”, {
......</script>
```

if someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Why invest time into that? `flash` is dead and everyone is happy about that.

Comment: It's just a example from their website, Personally I use the dash and hls like sources.